# Add overlay to Window at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, overlay

I'm writing a simple "tutorial" library that will allow developers to easily add step-by-step tutorials to their existing WPF applications.  The tutorials will help first time users of the application find their way around by adding an overlay that highlights a control and explains its purpose.  The end result will look something like this:

The regular application:
[image]

The overlay explaining the purpose of a control:
[image]

My question is this:  What's the most reliable and unobtrusive way to inject the overlay view into the current window?  The best I've come up with so far is to require the developer to add an attached property to whatever window will be hosting the overlay, and then add the necessary elements on the window's `Initialized` callback:

```
public static void IsTutorialOverlayCompatibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((Boolean)e.NewValue == true)
        {
            if (sender as Window != null)
            {
                Window window = (Window)sender;
                window.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler((o, eargs) =>
                    {
                        Grid newRootElement = new Grid();
                        newRootElement.Name = "HelpOverlayRoot";
                        if (window.Content as UIElement != null)
                        {
                            UIElement currentContent = (UIElement)window.Content;
                            window.Content = null;
                            newRootElement.Children.Add(currentContent);
                            newRootElement.Children.Add(new HelpOverlayControl());
                            window.Content = newRootElement;
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }
```

This feels like a hack, however, and I'm not sure that there isn't some edge case where this method will break the layout of the application.  In addition, it requires that the window's `Content` property be an instance of type `UIElement`.

I'd like to avoid forcing developers to change their XAML (i.e, adding a custom overlay `UserControl` to every window) in order to use my library.  What's the best way to add this kind of functionality to an existing WPF application?

Comment: You can try accessing the `AdornerLayer` of the window, which will let you draw anything wherever you want to.

Comment: Hi i am trying implement something similar. Did you managed to acheive something similar? without injecting views in XAML.